# Apple ID for enterprise use - Mac's and iOS devices

Tags: macos, ios, mac, apple-id, profile-manager

We found ourselves in a situation where a company supplied iPhone got linked to an employee's personal Apple ID account, and the phone is now useless to us, as the employee was terminated.

Is there a way using Apple's 'Profile Manager' to lock the Apple ID that are tied to Mac OS or iOS devices to their company email address?  We don't want people to be able to change that address.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take it to an apple store. They will lookup purchase history from serial number and if it shows that the company paid for it, they will wipe it for you.